# How can C# events keep track of instance methods?

Tags: c#, events

How is an event able to keep track of not only a method but also an object?

such as myobject here:

```
myPublisher.myEvent += myobject.FooMethod;
```

And full example program:

```
class Program
{
    private int Foos = 3;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        var p2 = new Program();
        p2.Foos = -10;
        p.MySecretFooIncreaser(null,null);
        var pub = new MyPublisher();
        pub.MyCrazyEvent += p.MySecretFooIncreaser;
        pub.MyCrazyEvent += p2.MySecretFooIncreaser;
        System.Console.WriteLine("time to raise event");
        pub.RaiseEvent();
    }
    private void MySecretFooIncreaser(Object sender, EventArgs e){
        System.Console.WriteLine($"increasing Foos from {Foos} to {++Foos}");
    }
}


class MyPublisher{
    public event EventHandler MyCrazyEvent = delegate {};
    public void RaiseEvent(){
        MyCrazyEvent?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Terminal output:

```
increasing Foos from 3 to 4
time to raise event
increasing Foos from 4 to 5
increasing Foos from -10 to -9
```

I found no place to read about this behaviour. Could anyone point me to a good resource for learning C# "low level, whats actually happening" the way one learns about the "git plumbing" vs "git porcelain". This is just one instance of where the teaching material I found[0] does not explain all thats needed to get a long term understanding.

[0] - C# 8.0 and .NET Core 3.0 + Exam Ref 70-483 Programming in C#

Comment: Well, [the documentation of the language is available online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/) -- everything from guides to the specification itself. The [source code for the compiler](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) is also available. Unfortunately, asking for resources is specifically off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: A unary delegate target is *defined* as the pair of methodinfo and target instance (which can be null); an event is a multicast delegate, so: zero (via null), one, or multiple unary targets.

Comment: One way to try to understand what is going on is to think "if I had to implement this behaviour, how would I do it?"  You've identified that the delegate knows both the method and the receiver, so *how would you implement it*? It wasn't magic; a person had to implement that.

Comment: I stated my question very badly and I realized that now. I'm new here at SO and not sure how to correct this now. My post was basically about "I noticed something I've never come across in my textbook when playing around with delegates myself, I tried looking for answers for this discovery but found none och do not know what this concept is called, I'm puzzled and dont know what else I have missed with regards to delegates". I understand now that the question is stated similar to "tell me implementation" which was not my intent.

Answer (score -1):

[Microsoft delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)

As Marc Gravell says, now found in the official docs.

> Delegates are similar to C++ function pointers, but delegates are fully object-oriented, and unlike C++ pointers to member functions, delegates encapsulate both an object instance and a method.

But in many cases the delegates are described only as:

> A delegate is a type that represents references to methods with a particular parameter list and return type.

Hence the confusion for a beginner such as myself.